# find(...) is undefined when fetching data with dynamic url using next.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, next.js, fetch-api

When I'm fetching data in my main page everything works as i wanted
but when I'm fetching data in another folder using same code but with dynamic url, I got an error when I'm trying to using methods on array. When i console.log fetched data, I got the same array as in my main page

When i delete Link and only want to see `book.title` it works. But i got error when i want to get data from resources.

###### mainpage.js

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  fetch('https://gnikdroy.pythonanywhere.com/api/book')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
}, []);

return(
       <div>
        {data.results.map((book, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <h1>{book.title}</h1>
            <Link href={`/reader/${book.id}`} passHref>
              <h2>
                {
                  book.resources.find(
                    ({ type }) => type === 'application/epub+zip'
                  ).uri
                }
              </h2>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
)
```

###### searchPage.js

```js
const router = useRouter();
const { name } = router.query;
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  fetch(`https://gnikdroy.pythonanywhere.com/api/book/?search=${name}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(data);
    });
}, []);

return(
      <div>
        {data.results.map((book, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <h1>{book.title}</h1>
            <Link href={`/reader/${book.id}`} passHref>
              <h2>
                {
                  book.resources.find(
                    ({ type }) => type === 'application/epub+zip'
                  ).uri
                }
              </h2>
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
)
```

[image: my error look like this]

my console.log inside fetch in searchPage.js

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response data is not getting resources fields sometime.
That's why `book.resources` can be undefined (or) null.

You can easily use [Optional Changing(?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Replace:

```
{
   book.resources?.find(
     ({ type }) => type === 'application/epub+zip'
   )?.uri || ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Wu Woo's answer, When consider How React render your code,

First will execute the `return` and then `useEffect` only in page load since you're not having values in `useEffect` Dependency array.

So in your scenario, you have *data = null* in initial page load. So when render below code, since *data = null* `data.results` can't use Arrays.map().

Then will execute the `useEffect` and inside there you set the value return from API call and set that value to data.

To avoid that render undefined error you must ensure `data.results` are not equal to null/undefined and when there is `data.results` render what you want.

You can achieve that by below ways.

1. The optional chaining operator (?.) as Wu Woo's answer which simplify accessing values through connected objects when it's possible that a reference or function may be `undefined or null`. Then it will not give above error when `book.resources` equal null/undefined.
2. render only when there is value for `data.results` and `book.resources` otherwise not like below.

   ```
     // Here conditionally check whether there is value for data?.results and if so render this.
    {data?.results && data.results.map((book, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <h1>{book.title}</h1>
      <Link href={`/reader/${book.id}`} passHref>
        <h2>
          {/* Here also conditionally check whether there is value for book?.resources and if so render this. */}
          { book?.resources &&
            book.resources.find(
              ({ type }) => type === 'application/epub+zip'
            ).uri
          }
        </h2>
      </Link>
    </div>
    ))}
   ```